# How to hide repetitive data Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello i have this function

```
 public function readData(){
    $TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
    ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
    ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
    ->select(
        'users.name as name',
        'group_user.user_id as id',
        'groups.name as groupname',
        'meetings.owned_by_id as meetings'
    )
    ->get();


    return $TableB1;

   }
```

it returns data like this :

```
[{"name":"Mohamed Adel","id":6,"groupname":"Team Mohamed","meetings":6},{"name":"Mohamed Adel","id":6,"groupname":"Team Mohamed","meetings":6},{"name":"Norman Osborn","id":2,"groupname":"Team Mohamed","meetings":2},{"name":"Harry Osborn","id":3,"groupname":"Team Harry","meetings":3}]
```

as you can see i have 2 Mohamed Adel objects how to hide them
or how to query right so i don't get repetition each time

i edited the function

```
public function readData(){
$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
->select(
    'users.name as name',
    'group_user.user_id as id',
    'groups.name as groupname',
    'meetings.owned_by_id as meetings'
)
->groupBy('users.id')
->get();
```

i get this error : https://ibb.co/FqPd1Wz

Comment: Simple use  groupBy('name')

Comment: You could use `distinct()`.

Comment: how to use distinct() in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `groupBy` with query builder

```
    public function readData()
    {
        $TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
        ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
        ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
        ->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
        ->select(
            'users.name as name',
            'group_user.user_id as id',
            'groups.name as groupname',
            'meetings.owned_by_id as meetings'
        )
        ->groupBy('users.name')
        ->get();
        return $TableB1;
    }
```

You can read more about `groupBy` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: I think it's better to use an ID, rather than a name for homonyms

Comment: thank you very much for your answer i tried it but i got this error Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sedracrm.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select users.name

Comment: @Saromase I provide the solution on the basis of his output, Both the answer will work perfectly yours and mine

Comment: @AnkurTiwari, sure, both answer work good, but it's only a tips.

Comment: @Saromase, Yes bro, I understand, but most of the people using the incremented id in every table, So in some case, it is not a good idea to group the records by id, That is the reason I used `groupBy` on the `name` column.

Comment: @AnkurTiwari hum, good thinks, in my table i use `users > id` and `other table > user_id`, but i see why you group by name, thank for answer

Comment: @mohamedadel can you post your query here, after updating it

Comment: `$TableB1 = \DB::table('users')
    ->join('group_user', 'users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')
    ->join('groups', 'groups.id', '=', 'group_user.group_id')
    ->join('meetings', 'users.id', '=', 'meetings.owned_by_id')
    ->select(
        'users.name as name',
        'group_user.user_id as id',
        'groups.name as groupname',
        'meetings.owned_by_id as meetings'
    )
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->get();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `groupBy` method like this :

```
->groupBy('group_user.user_id')
```

See this documentation link [Laravel Query Builder Group By](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer i tried it but i got this error
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sedracrm.users.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `users`.`name`

Comment: @mohamedadel can you update your question with new request, and error please.
Thank

Comment: Done any help will be appreciated